# open reactjs sideNav on click

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to open `react sideNav` bar on `button` click. I'm referring these articles to do this:

https://github.com/gauravchl/react-simple-sidenav

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-sidenav

https://gauravchl.github.io/react-simple-sidenav/demo/

I have implemented it correctly but i'm stuck on opening the `sideNav` on clicking a `button`.

```
<div>
    <MenuIcon onClick={() => this.setState({showNav: true})}/>
    <SideNav
        title="Simple Sidenav"
        items={['Item 1', 'Item 2']}
        openFromRight="true"
        showNav = {this.state.showNav}
    />
</div>
```

If i give `showNav = 'true'` , the `sideNav` opens by default when the page opens. if i give `showNav = {this.state.showNav}` i get an error:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>. See div > App > html.
printWarning @ bundle.js:11845
bundle.js:35792 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNav' of null
    at Notification.render (bundle.js:35792)
    at bundle.js:26635
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:25914)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (bundle.js:26634)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (bundle.js:26661)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:26201)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:26097)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:18478)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (bundle.js:25215)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (bundle.js:22220)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked the `github` link, in description they didn't define the initial state of the `showNav` variable, you need to add this part in your component, to define the initial value it will work:

```
getInitialState : function() {
   return {
     showNav: false,
   };
},
```

If you check the project file `demo/src/layout.js`, `showNav` is defined, in description they didn't wrote a working code, mainly focused on how to use `SideNav`, a sample code.

**Update**:

```
import react from 'react';
import SideNav, {MenuIcon} from 'react-simple-sidenav';

React.createClass({

  getInitialState : function() {
     return {
        showNav: false,
     };
  },

  render() {
    .....
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Initilize the state for 'showNav'

```
this.state = {
 showNav: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false)
    return (

    <MenuIcon className="MenuIconStyle" onClick={() => setShowNav(true)} />
                <SideNav
                    showNav={showNav}
                    onHideNav={() => setShowNav(false)}
                    items={['Item 1', 'Item 2']}
                    titleStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#4CAF50' }}
                    itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
                    itemHoverStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#CDDC39' }}
                    openFromRight={false}
                />
```

Comment: Hi user. Could you please explain how your code works and solves the question?